# tmux set session variable for different sessions

Tags: environment-variables, tmux

I'm simply trying to set a shell env for a tmux session. At first it works like expected:

```
export MY_VARIABLE=123
tmux new-session

# in session
echo $MY_VARIABLE
-> 123
```

Now I detach the session and create a second one:

```
tmux detach

echo $MY_VARIABLE
-> 123

export MY_VARIABLE=456

echo $MY_VARIABLE
-> 456

tmux new-session

# in new session
echo $MY_VARIABLE
-> 123

# list session to see it is really a new one
tmux list-sessions
-> 0: 1 windows ...
-> 1: 1 windows ... (attached)
```

If I exit the old session (not detach), then it works as expected. It looks like the variables are synced between sessions? How can I break this up to have separate $MY_VARIABLE after starting a tmux session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a feature of tmux: variable sharing. By connecting to different sockets, different variables can be set (found out by [this stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180600/tmux-variables-sharing-between-sessions)):

```
export MY_VARIABLE=123
tmux -L socket_name new-session

# in session
echo $MY_VARIABLE
-> 123

tmux -L socket_name detach

export MY_VARIABLE=456

tmux -L another_socket new-session

# in new session
echo $MY_VARIABLE
-> 456
```